# Function to make multiple scatterplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have this dataframe:

```
set.seed(50)
data <- data.frame(age=c(rep("juv", 10), rep("ad", 10)),
                   sex=c(rep("m", 10), rep("f", 10)),
                   size=c(rep("large", 10), rep("small", 10)),
                   length=rnorm(20),
                   width=rnorm(20),
                   height=rnorm(20))
```

Using this dataframe, I need to make 9 scatterplots, that plot each continuous variable against each factor variable. So I need to make these scatterplots:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(length, width, group=age, colour=age)) + geom_point()
ggplot(data, aes(length, height, group=age, colour=age)) + geom_point()
ggplot(data, aes(width, height, group=age, colour=age)) + geom_point()

ggplot(data, aes(length, width, group=sex, colour=sex)) + geom_point()
ggplot(data, aes(length, height, group=sex, colour=sex)) + geom_point()
ggplot(data, aes(width, height, group=sex, colour=sex)) + geom_point()

ggplot(data, aes(length, width, group=size, colour=size)) + geom_point()
ggplot(data, aes(length, height, group=size, colour=size)) + geom_point()
ggplot(data, aes(width, height, group=size, colour=size)) + geom_point()
```

However, I want to be able to make these 9 scatterplots using a function. Something like this:

```
makeScatterplots <- function(x.variable, y.variable, my.factor){

  ggplot(dataframe, aes(x.variable, y.variable, group=my.factor, colour=my.factor)) + geom_point()

}
```

How can I make an function, which takes the x variables, y variables and grouping factors, that will compute these 9 scatterplots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `aes_string()` inside `ggplot()` and supply `x.variable` and `y.variable` as names (characters), and also use `print()` around `ggplot()` call.

```
makeScatterplots <- function(dataframe,x.variable, y.variable, my.factor){
  print(ggplot(dataframe, aes_string(x=x.variable,y= y.variable, 
                     group=my.factor, colour=my.factor)) + geom_point())  
}

makeScatterplots(data,"length","width","age")
```

### UPDATE

Merging together this and previous [OP question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785423/apply-box-plots-to-multiple-variables)

This function will produce all possible combination of x, y and factor variables.

```
makeScatterplots <- function(dataframe,x.variable, y.variable, my.factor){
  gg<-expand.grid(x.variable,y.variable,my.factor)
  gg<-data.frame(lapply(gg, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  apply(gg,1,function(x) ggplot(data,aes_string(x=x[1],y=x[2],color=x[3]))+geom_point())
}
```

Comment: So I tried calling function like this: `makeScatterplots(data,c("width","height","length"), c("length","width","height"), c("age","sex","size"))` but it only makes a single plot. I need function to deal with varying numbers x variables, y variables and factors.